# How to use a relation generated after replace() in a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to perform a `LEFT JOIN` on two tables. Both have a column named WEBSITE. One is populated with the protocol like `http://abc.com` and the other is without the protocol like `abc.com`.

I am trying to JOIN these table w.r.t. WEBSITE column. I tried to replace the protocol and then perform the join like this:

```
SELECT replace(WEBSITE, 'http://', '') as SITENAME FROM WITHPROTOCOLTABLE LEFT JOIN WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE ON (WITHPROTOCOLTABLE.SITENAME = WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE.WEBSITE)
```

But I get the Error: `column WITHPROTOCOLTABLE.SITENAME does not exist`

How can I perform the `JOIN`. Please advice.

---

EDIT:

### TABLES:

```
WITHPROTOCOLTABLE

website           somedata
----------------|---------------
http://abc.com  |  abcdef
http://xyz.com  |  xyzabc

WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE

website
-------
abc.com
xyz.com
```

Comment: can u show your tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `WITHPROTOCOLTABLE` and `WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE` are two different tables or views then use the `REPLACE` function in your joining condition like this:

```
SELECT replace(WEBSITE, 'http://', '') as SITENAME
FROM WITHPROTOCOLTABLE
LEFT JOIN WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE
      ON (REPLACE(WITHPROTOCOLTABLE.WEBSITE, 'http://', '')
           = WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE.WEBSITE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are here saying that you are joining table with `WEBSITE column` but you have used `WITHPROTOCOLTABLE.SITENAME = WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE.WEBSITE` ie "SiteName".
Second thing make alias for your tables to avoid confusion.

Query:

```
SELECT replace(wp.WEBSITE, 'http://', '') as SITENAME FROM WITHPROTOCOLTABLE wp
LEFT JOIN WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE wop ON (REPLACE(wp.WEBSITE, 'http://', '') = wop.WEBSITE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the adivse...I will use aliasing in my queries :)

Answer (score 0):

Aliasing a value/calculation/whatever using `AS` does not put the alias into a specific table. Use

```
LEFT JOIN WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE ON SITENAME = WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE.WEBSITE
```

to join the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try This One

```
SELECT replace(WEBSITE, 'http://', '') as SITENAME FROM WITHPROTOCOLTABLE
 LEFT JOIN WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE ON (replace(WEBSITE, 'http://', '') = WITHOUTPROTOCOLTABLE.WEBSITE)
```